# How to target all elements in a list except the li containing the trigger element with jquery

Tags: jquery

I've been trying to make a ul controlled by radio buttons. When a button is checked, I would like all li's, except the final (other) li and the li containing the checked radio button to disappear. I think I am quite close but I can't work out how to exclude the checked radio button's li from being hidden. My guess is that the .not(this).parent('li') section isn't targetting the correct element, but I can't work out what it should be instead. Here is the javascript I've made so far.

```
$('input.addressradio').change(function(){ 
  $(this).parents('ul.address').find('li').not(this).parent("li").hide();   
  $(this).parents('ul.address').find('li.allbutonetarget').show();
    return false;
});
```

And here is the html I would like it to power.

```
<ul class="address collectionaddressnewhideY">
<li>
<input value="saved1" type="radio" class="include oneofmanyfieldset addressradio" name="collectionaddressradio" id="collectionaddressradiosaved1"></input>
<span class="collectionaddresssaved1 savedaddress">
</span>
</li>
 <li>
 <input value="saved2" type="radio" class="include oneofmanyfieldset addressradio" name="collectionaddressradio" id="collectionaddressradiosaved2"></input>
<span class="collectionaddresssaved2 savedaddress">
</span>
</li>
<li><input value="saved3" type="radio" class="include oneofmanyfieldset addressradio" name="collectionaddressradio" id="collectionaddressradiosaved3"></input>
<span class="collectionaddresssaved3 savedaddress">
</span>
</li>
<li class="allbutonetarget"><input value="other" type="radio" class="include oneofmanyfieldset addressradio" name="collectionaddressradio" id="collectionaddressradioother">Other </input>
<span>
</span>
</li>
</ul>
```

If someone could point me in the right direction and let me know where this is going wrong I'd be really grateful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('input.addressradio').on('change', function(){ 
  $(this).parent().siblings('li').not(this).not('.allbutonetarget').hide();   
}); ​
```

Answer (score 0):

The `.not()` function can take a DOM elements or a jQuery object containing a DOM element to test against. If you want to exclude the parent of `this`, then you want to pass `$(this).parent()` to the `.not()` function, like so:

```
$('input.addressradio').change(function(){ 
  $(this).parents('ul.address').find('li').not($(this).parent("li")).hide();   
  $(this).parents('ul.address').find('li.allbutonetarget').show();
    return false;
});
```

To go into a bit more detail as to why your code was going wrong, you were getting a set of `<li>` elements, then attempting to exclude `this` (which is an `<input>` element, and therefore never going to be in the original set) rather than the parent of `this` (which is an `<li>` element, and may be in the original set) from that set. Since none of the elements matched `this` (How could they? They're not the same type), the entire set was returned by the call to `.not()`, and they were all hidden.

Comment: Thanks for the solution and especially for spelling out why it was wrong for me

Answer (score 0):

You are not excluding this from your radio buttons, but from your `li`s:

```
$(this).parents('ul.address').find('li').not(this).parent("li").hide()
```

You should first find all radios, then exclude this, then find their parents:

```
$(this).parents('ul.address').find('.addressradio').not(this).parent("li").hide()
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
$('input.addressradio').click(function(){
    $('li').hide();
    $(this).parent().show();
    $('input[value="other"]').parent().show();
})
```

**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rbSTF/1/)** example.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('input.addressradio').change(function() {
    $(this).parent().siblings('li').not('.allbutonetarget').hide();
    return false;//keeps this one from being checked? you want that?
});
```

- The `li` is the parent tag siblings selector.
- The `.not()` excludes
  that one (with that class) from the `.hide`.
- The one with the
  currently checked radio is excluded by it NOT being a sibling of
  itself by definition.